# Как собрать JavaFX проект c Gradle или Maven в Intelij Idea?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Пишу проект на JavaFX и Scene Builder. Столкнулся с необходимостью собрать нормально проект. По отзывам в интернете советуют использовать сборщики либо Gradle либо Maven, вместо стандартного из Intelij Idea, да и на выходе когда собираю исполняемый Jar file там много всего в выходной папке, включая папку .idea.

Когда я создавал проект, я не выбирал ни gradle, ни maven. Обычный JavaFX проект.

**Как собрать проект с Gradle или Maven в Intelij Idea?**

В идеале нужно чтобы появилась папка со всеми ресурсами, используемыми библиотеками и exe файлом, который бы запускал мою программу на любом компьютере под Windows

Структура моего проекта:

[![Structure][1]][1]

**Редакция:**

Добавил поддержку Maven в свой проект, сделал build, и сделал compile. Появилась папка target, в этой папке есть папка classes, но там нет никаких классов.

**Как дальше продолжить компиляцию и запустить проект через Maven?**

[image: Structure 2]
[image: Structure 3]

Comment: ПКМ на проекте (слева, там где структура файлов). Add Framework support. Из списка выбираете Maven. Настраиваете pom файл и все. А на данный момент структура проекта не мавеновская вообще.

Comment: @Tsyklop так да, я об этом написал,что при создании проекта я не указывал, что это Maven или Gradle проект, это обычный проект, а какой должна быть структура Gradle или Maven я понятия не имею. ВОзможно ли вообще переделать оычный проект для того чтобы его собрать с Gradle или maven? или для этого нужно было чтобы я при создани проекта это указывал?

Comment: ПКМ на проекте (слева, там где структура файлов). Add Framework support. Из списка выбираете Maven. Настраиваете pom файл и все.

Comment: C maven вроде ничего суперсложного нет, а вот с Gradle непонятки - постою послушаю

Comment: с мавеном все просто, но я не уверен, что мавеном получится просто создать лаунчер, а вот градлом можно сделать такую составную сборку, но я не смогу подсказать как.